# $\cot x - \tan x = 2\cot 2x$, but the period on the left is $\pi$, while on the right it's $\pi/2$. Shouldn't the periods match?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

It's not difficult to show $$\cot x - \tan x = 2\cot 2x$$ The period of LHS is $T_1 = \pi$ but the period of RHS is $T_2 = \pi /2$ . Why are $T_1$ and $T_2$ not equal? So we can't use that identity for solving problems?

Comment: $\cot(x+\pi/2) - \tan(x + \pi/2) = -\tan x + \cot x = \cot x - \tan x$

Comment: Why do you think that the period of LHS is $\pi$?

Comment: @zhoraster Because the period of $\tan x$ and $\cot x$ is $\pi$ .

Comment: @SHW As nice comments above have shown, what you can conclude is that $\pi$ is a period of LHS. It is not necessarily the fundamental period.

Comment: @samjoe Therefore what we can say about the period of addition or subtraction of two periodic functions ?

Answer (score 0):

Say $f(x) = 2\cot (2x)$ and let $T_2$ be a period for $f$, then $$f(x+T_2)= f(x)\implies \cot (2x+2T_2)= \cot 2x$$

Mark $\alpha = 2x$ (so clearly $\alpha$  can be any angle) then we have $$\cot (\alpha +2T_2) = \cot (\alpha)$$

and thus $2T_2$ is a period for $\cot$ so $2T_2 = \pi$

---

But $\pi/2$ is also period for $g(x)=\cot x-\tan x$: $$ g(x+\pi/2) = \cot(x+\pi/2)-\tan (x+\pi/2)$$ $$ =\cot(x-\pi/2)-\tan (x-\pi/2)$$
$$ =-\cot(\pi/2-x)+\tan (\pi/2-x)$$
$$ =-\tan(x)+\cot (x)=g(x)$$